# xslt 1.0 base64 encode the content of a template

Tags: php, xml, xslt, base64, xslt-1.0

How can I encode the content of a template in base64, using XSLT 1.0?

Edit: using serialization mode, runing in PHP enviroment

It's like i have a template like this:

```
<xsl:template name="test">
    <test 
      gender="male" 
      name1="TEST" 
      name2="TEST">
      <sometags>
            <tag></tag>
        </sometags>
    </test>
</xsl:template>
```

and I want the output to be like this:

```
<base64>PHRlc3QgDQoJCSAgZ2VuZGVyPSJtYWxlIiANCgkJICBuYW1lMT0iVEVTVCIgDQoJCSAgbmFtZTI9IlRFU1QiPg0KICAgICAgICAgIDxzb21ldGFncz4NCgkJCQk8dGFnPjwvdGFnPg0KCQkJPC9zb21ldGFncz4NCgkJPC90ZXN0Pg==</base64>
```

Comment: I think i found an other way. <xsl:variable name="data">                <xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($test)" mode="serialize"/>   </xsl:variable> <xsl:value-of select="php:function('base64_encode', string($data))" />

Comment: That may work, apparently you already have a serialization mode (not in your question). Though my answer shows a cross-processor way of doing it. Your approach will only work if a processor enables extension functions and is run in a PHP environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mukhul Gandhi [created a Base64 encoder](http://gandhimukul.tripod.com/xslt/base64-xslt.html) that runs in XSLT 1.0. If you can switch to XSLT 2.0, you can create stylesheet functions to do the same.

However, because you seem to mean to encode nodes into strings, you should not create nodes, but strings instead:

Re-apply the result of your template using the [`node-set` extension function](http://exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/) (supported by (almost?) all XSLT 1.0 processors) and write something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    <xsl:text>&lt;/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
    <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
    <xsl:text>="</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Note: not tested, and you probably want to extend it to add indentation, processing of other nodes like processing instructions and comments, and in the case of attributes, to escape any quotes in the strings.

In XSLT 3.0 you can achieve the same using the [`fn:serialize` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-serialize).